# Make modification of add_to_cart button specific to single page

Tags: plugins, functions, woocommerce-offtopic

I am using WooCommerce for the eCommerce part of my WordPress site.

When using the `add_to_cart` button I want it to say "read more" on a specific webpage only.

So far I have found the code to change the button text:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_product_single_add_to_cart_text', 'woo_custom_cart_button_text');

function woo_custom_cart_button_text() {
return__('Read More','woocommerce'); }
```

The question is, how do I make this apply to the appearance of the `add_to_cart`  button on a single page of my website? The page is not a shop page. It is a normal webpage where is have the description of products and the associated treatment. The button is there to take them to the product page.

Answer (score 0):

Why not add a regular button with link to the product page, as in 
`<a href..><button></button></a>`?

Comment: Becuase I want the price to be showing next to the button.

Answer (score 0):

You use two different text for product listing page and product details page.

1. Open Wordpress admin panel, go to Appearance > Theme Editor 
   Open functions.php theme file
2. Add the following code at the bottom of function.php file
3. Save the changes and check your website. The custom text in add to cart button should show up now.

```
 // To change add to cart text on single product page
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_single_add_to_cart_text', 'woocommerce_custom_single_add_to_cart_text' ); 
function woocommerce_custom_single_add_to_cart_text() {
    return __( 'Buy Now', 'woocommerce' ); 
}

// To change add to cart text on product archives(Collection) page
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text', 'woocommerce_custom_product_add_to_cart_text' );  
function woocommerce_custom_product_add_to_cart_text() {
    return __( 'Buy Now', 'woocommerce' );
}
```

Comment: Thanks, However im not looking at changing the text on the 'single product page'. I want to change the text when using the shortcode [add_to_cart ids="xxx"] to read learnmore on a specific page of my website. Any ideas?